# How do you put the datetime in the guage chart in human readable format

Tags: javascript, highcharts

my php script output is this:

```
[y:45,date:1371126021000]
```

\my function is this:

```
(document).ready(function() {

 function request_cpu_Data() {

    $.ajax({

        url: 'get_cpu.php', 
        success: function(data) {
        var point = cpu_chart.series[0].points[0];
        alert(data);
        point.update(data);
        setTimeout(request_cpu_Data, 10); 
        },
        cache: false

    });
}
```

\n

```
 plotOptions: {
            gauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.y + '<br>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', this.point.date);
                    }
                },
            }
        },


         series: [{
            name: 'CPU',
            data: [0]
        }]
```

my gauge is not updating. Any ideas what migh be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert that value. Instead use dataLabel formatter: http://jsfiddle.net/AVLeH/

```
    plotOptions: {
        gauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', this.y);
                }
            },
        }
    },
```

Comment: Fus, I really appreciate this. I have one quick question, get_cpu.php returns two values, one is the date, the other is the cpu. I do this: var point = cpu_chart.series[0].points[0]; var newVal=myObj[1];point.update(newVal); for the cpu value and every ajax call, I get a new cpu value. How do I do this for the date part and pass it to the gauge chart. I haven't seen any documentation and I am kinda stuck.

Comment: Where this date should be displayed?

Comment: Your point should be an object, for example `{y: CPU_value, date: CPU_date}`. Then in formatter you have access to `date` or anything similar, see: http://jsfiddle.net/AVLeH/1/

Comment: Fus, Ok I got this but, how do you update point after each poll?

Comment: @Fus, I've udpated my original post with your recommendations.

Comment: Your PHP output shouldn't be: `{y: value, date: timstamp}` ? I mean object instead of array. See live example: http://jsfiddle.net/AVLeH/3/